# What is the term for a stalemate or locked board in Magic?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I listen to the [Limited Resources Podcast](http://lrcast.com/) quite a bit, and I always hear this word used that sounds like "Parody". In context:

> My opponent and I were at "parody"; neither of us could do anything.

I cannot find this term anywhere online. I've searched for "parody", "parroty", "peredi"... It must sound silly, but ***what is this word they are using***?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parity, in this context meaning equality (of game state, in some sense). In general, equality of game state doesn't necessarily mean a stalemate or locked board, but in Magic it's often the case that the player to make the first move is at a disadvantage.

Comment: Ugh, thanks. I feel foolish. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(sports)

Comment: So not like this? http://asset2.cbsistatic.com/cnwk.1d/i/tim/2013/03/06/fmimg4855090770787555538_257x386.jpg

Comment: ...but yeah as far as it relates to Magic, I guess a good example would be a bunch of vanilla `2/3`s on each side. The attacking player is at a disadvantage (not considering combat tricks, etc.). Another term I've heard is "Draw-Go".

Comment: @WesleyMurch Or just such that things will trade, you'll be tapped out and die on the swing back, or even a control matchup when whoever tries to cast a spell first will have less mana to back up their play, or the fact that playing your instant first lets your opponent respond. It does sometimes depend on context; if you're both at 1 making the first move might win you the game.

Comment: Right, exactly. Thanks, for the knock on the head. I didn't realize this was a word, and now I realize it's the opposite of "disparity" (I'm learning things!).

Comment: *the player to make the first move is at a disadvantage* - in chess, this is called [*zugzwang*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zugzwang).